# preg_replace </color='#any hexadecimal color code'> to </color> in php

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to replace the

```
 </color='#any hexadecimal color code '>
```

to

```
</color>
```

I have tried following but nothing happened

```
$bio_info="some string </color='#any hexadecimal color code'>";    
preg_replace("/</color/", "</color>", $bio_info);
```

Comment: Nothing happened? You should have gotten an error complaining about unrecognized modifiers in the regexp, because you forgot to escape the `/`.

Answer (score 1):

Your regexp doesn't include the `='#any hexadecimal color code '` part of the tag that you want to replace. You also forgot to escape the `/`. And you need to assign the result to a variable if you want to use it.

```
$bio_info="some string </color='#any hexadecimal color code'>";  
$result = preg_replace('#</color=[^>]*>#', '</color>', $bio_info);
```

I've used a different regexp delimiter so I don't need to escape the `/`. `[^>]*` will match any sequence of characters other than `>`, so this matches the rest of the tag.

Answer (score 0):

Simply fill with any char between opening and closing tag :

```
$bio_info="some string </color='#any hexadecimal color code'>";    
preg_replace("/<\/color.*>/", "</color>", $bio_info);
```